# I can't pass parameters from google excel to apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I added a picture button from google sheet, when it clicks on the picture, the specified column should be +1.

For example, the field I specified today is "D4", when I click on the picture, the number in the field "D4" should be +1.

But I have confirmed that my sheet, column and function name are set, but it still says

"Script function click("D4"); could not be found"

This Google Sheets link：
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jJSlSFIapnxpTS7DbkQTJyJXRs7yoKHKR4JLrh0lffQ/edit?usp=sharing

My current screen：
[image]

My Assign script：

[image]

When he clicks：
[image]

The expected result should be
[image]

我的Apps Script為
[image]

Did I write something wrong?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `"Script function click("D4"); could not be found"` and your showing script. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And, can you provide your current script as the text instead of the image?

Comment: Can you show us what your `Assign script` dialog says?

Comment: @Tanaike that's ok , my poor English skill also.
I am use google translate.
As this update , I shared my Google Sheets link in my article.
Anyone can edit him and know the situation.

Comment: What is the Assign script mean?

Comment: @TheWizEd oh i know Assign script mean now.My Assign script is updata in my article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make sure that you're using only the name of the function without any parameters or `()` when assigning a Script to a shape in this case just `click`:

[image]

Otherwise the reported error will appear. Unfortunately it seems that passing parameters when assigning the Script is a feature request see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232828544. You'll need to specify the affected rows in the code just as in the example:

```
const range = sheet.getRange("D4");
```

Comment: ok i'll study the example you sent me.

Comment: As an added note, I'd like passing parameters when assigning the script.
Because if I want to add 100 buttons, then I have to write 100 functions.
 I don't think it's efficient to do this.

Comment: That's currently not possible and it's a feature request on Google's end, your use case is very similar to the one described in this open Issue tracker entry https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232828544. I'd recommend you to give a +1 there, hopefully that gets implemented in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Let me know I'm not the only one who wants to do this.I already gave a +1,hopefully that gets implemented in the future.